# Insert 3 images for sheet using vba

Tags: excel, vba, image, format

I have to create an Excel macro that allows the users to choose an unlimited number of photos from the pc and that automatically sets them three for pages; for example if the users chooses 9 pictures I will get 3 sheets with 3 pictures each.

I know how to let the user choose the pictures but I have no idea how to set them 3 for page

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub Images()
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .ButtonName = "Invia"
    .Title = "Seleziona una foto"
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "JPG", "*.JPG"
    .Filters.Add "JPEG File Interchange Format", "*.JPEG"
    .Filters.Add "Graphics Interchange Format", "*.GIF"
    .Filters.Add "Portable Network Graphics", "*.PNG"
    .Filters.Add "Tag Image File Format", "*.TIFF"
    .Filters.Add "All Pictures", "*.*"

    If .Show = -1 Then

        For i = 1 To .SelectedItems.count
        Dim img As Object
        Set img = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(.SelectedItems(i))

        'Scale image size
        'img.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 0.75, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
        'img.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 0.75, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft

        'Position Image
         // I think here is the problem

        'Set image sizes in points (72 point per inch)
        img.Width = 150
        img.Height = 150
        Next i

    Else
        MsgBox ("Cancelled.")
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @BigBen I don't know how to set them 3 per page

Comment: Do You want 9pics in one worksheet with 3pics on every printed page or 9pics with 3worksheets with 3pics on every sheet ?